# jQuery plugin that supports drag-n-sort list with deletion and limit on list-length?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm building a feature for a website that allows a user to

1. Enter a string and add that string as an item to a list
2. Sort the list by dragging the items up and down
3. Delete items from the list
4. Enforce a limit to the length of the list. For example say I want to limit each list to 10 items or fewer. If a user tried to add an 11th item that should not be allowed.
5. Communicate actions to back-end server/database: whenever an element is added, deleted, or dragged to a different position in the list, that information needs to be sent back to the back-end server/database

I looked at `jQuery UI Sortable` plugin but it doesn't really do what I need. Is there any jQuery plugin that does the above 5 things?

If I need to modify `jQuery UI Sortable` (or something similar) to do what I need, how do I do that? I'm very new to this so any help is really appreciated.

I prefer jQuery as I'm already using it for this project. But if some other libraries is more appropriate for this purpose I'd love to hear about them too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of this can be done programmatically with the jQuery-ui Sortable list.  There are different events that you can hook into.  For instance, you'd want to hook into the `update` event on the list to send the order to a back-end server, and use the sortable's `serialize()` method to uh... serialize the list's order.  Like this:

```
$('ul#my-list').sortable({
  update: function(event, ui) {
    $.post(
      '/url/to/your/server',
      $(this).sortable('serialize')
    );
  }
});
```

This is just example code, so you'll have to tweak it to get it to do just what you need.

For deleting items in a list, that's as simple as adding some sort of a delete button on each element, and just removing it from the DOM:

```
<ul id="my-list">
  <li>item 1 <a href="#" class="delete">X</a></li>
  <li>item 2 <a href="#" class="delete">X</a></li>
</ul>

$('ul#my-list a.delete').live('click', function(e) {
  $(this).parent().fadeOut().remove();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

As far as adding items to the list, well there are many ways to do this, I'll leave it to you as I feel I've written for long enough :)